# How can i rotate an item/bone on its own pivot?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm animating a character but the camera doesn't show the items on orthographic perspective, so i need to (on this case) rotate the character neck but on that perspective it's pretty hard to do it, but is there any solution to rotate it like if it were on orghographic perspective?

[image]

**Thanks in regard.**

Comment: please add some image and description

Comment: Have you tried **R Y Y**?